# How to disable javascript from <head> on a single page or div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I need to turn off some jquery fade in and out on a single page because it causes it not to load properly.

The page is not public to view, but it has tabs created in css when I click the tabs it fades out as if I were changing the page and then nothing loads back up.

Is it possible to change the javascript, or disable it on a single page??

Thnx

Comment: Can you comment the code out? Without seeing your code, it's really hard to find a solution.

Comment: OK security is disabled, you can view on http://morrisentertainment.ca/wp/?page_id=27

Comment: It is in Wordpress, the code is applied to a plugin that adds the code to the head on every page.  the code is . . 

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $('body').css('display', 'none');
        $('body').fadeIn(500);

        $("a").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                linkLocation = this.href;
                $("body").fadeOut(500, redirectPage);
            });
 
            function redirectPage() {
                 window.location = linkLocation;
                 }
                });
                </script>

Answer (score 0):

Add the following **after** the default JS code is included, in order to override its behaviour.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function()
   {
      $("a").unbind("click");

      $("a").click(function(event)
      {
         event.preventDefault();
      });
   });
</script>
```

This should remove the biding that the `<a>` element has with the fade effect.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Comment: That'll definitely do it. If the only thing the plugin does is make the page fade in and out then I'd remove it altogether if I could.

Comment: It was specifically requested by the Client, otherwise I would.

Comment: The Above script looked good, but doesn't work . Is there a way to disable it by adding a condition of if it's on the URL of a specific page?

Comment: Or how about some kind of condition that only adds it to pages that load a new page in the current window?  The other links do load a new page, just hide a single div. . .

Comment: @MattDouglas I've edited my answer, please take a look. Since the code that creates the biding only executes after the `document` is *ready*, we have to the same to remove it.

Comment: This Prevents the Error, but prevents the switching of the tabs. . . 

[link]http://morrisentertainment.ca/wp/?page_id=27[/link]

Comment: @MattDouglas you're right, I didn't account for that. Rebind only the location changing code to the `<a>` element. I've edited the code based on the original provided JS, take a look.

Comment: @MattDouglas although I might add... I don't quite understand how the content is loaded based on the provided location, since all that does is change the `window.location` property, much like just clicking the link.

Comment: Is there anyway to just have the script NOT load on a specific url?

Comment: @MattDouglas I've noticed that the code on the link you provide already works. Feel free to share your solution with us.